# (C# / Unity) Fastest way to traverse a 2D array or fastest way to find an integer in an array of integers (Cellular Automata)

Tags: c#, performance

(Question is in C#, what I'm stating about Unity and Cellular Automata is to provide context)

I'm writing a Cellular Automata system and I need to update it with new generation very fast in every 0.1 seconds.

Each cell is displayed with a GameObject on the scene, which is cached.

Problem is, when I want to find whether the current cell should survive or not, I need to search an integer in an array of integers (which is number of neighbors thas cells has) which is very slow.

Note that this happens 8000+ times per 0.1 second.

I've used Array and Index.Of() static function which was very slow. Next I found out about HashSet and it's better but not fast enough since I still find FPS drops due to hiccups on calling HashSet.Contains() to do my search.

The array of integers is very small actually, about 5 integers at most (I actually need two of these sets for both survive and born rules mind you).

So I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this search in C#.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I found out Lists are faster for small amount of items like in my case. I've tested and it's better but still lags.

Comment: What does **update** mean? I am pretty sure the bottleneck of "updating" a GameObject is several orders of magnitude larger than finding an integer out of 5 integers. Btw, even if we are talking about microoptimizations here, a List<T> cannot possibly be faster than an array (probably the compiler will optimize it to get equal performance, so you are most likely not measuring correctly, or not coding something correctly).

Comment: 1) Yes 2) No 3) Yes. I use profiler and can actually see the bottleneck. I can post pictures if you want. In case of Arrays being faster, I know 2 ways to do it: first by a loop and checking one by one and second by that Index.Of static call of Array class. Didn't try first one because I thought calling a built-in function is faster (might be wrong) but second one is slower than List and even HashSet. Since what I'm doing can be parallelized I was thinking of doing it simultaneously via different threads maybe?

Comment: So, to clarify, you have 8000 objects, each of which has an array of up to 5 items? If you cannot improve the algorithm and really need to search individual 5-elements arrays, there is nothing much that can be faster than a simple array search. I would either reconsider if the algorithm can be changed, or try to parallelize (in the best case, write a shader and let GPU take care of it).

Comment: There is a 2D array of bools and I have to traverse it and on each cell find number of it's "true" neighbors and then test it against that array of 5 numbers and if it's there, toggle it. I'm actually thinking of parallelizing it but with threads. Is there a benefit in doing it with shaders? BTW I don't know either but I think threads are easier to grasp. Thanks.

Comment: It's likely that simple paralellization (`Parallel.For`) won't help much in this case, even with partitioning, but without some actual code, it's impossible to tell. For test, I created 8000 objects, each with 5 item arrays with random integers, and my [i7 mobile CPU from 2012](http://ark.intel.com/products/64899) is able to process all 8000 objects 8000 times per second (~126 microseconds per 8000 objects). Try posting your actual code. Regarding shaders, GPU gives you massive parallelization (100s of cores), compared to (say) 4 cores on a reasonably fast CPU. But I wouldn't go this road yet.

Comment: Also, compare your code with other online sources to see if you're doing some inefficient. For example, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joelmartinez/1194013) uses `Parallel.For` to parallelize processing, and doesn't use any additional arrays for processing.

Comment: Here is the code I call on each generation: http://pastebin.com/bcA3C6vL